# npm install fails to install dependencies for a nano-react-app that i created

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, npm, npm-install

I used **npx nano-react-app tictactoe** to create a new app . Then i used **npm install** so that it installs the dependencies. This is the **package.json** that came along with the nano-react-app:

```
  "name": "tictactoe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-nano-react-app": "^0.1.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-alpha.3.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "nano-react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

**npm install** gives the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/sushrutkamat/Documents/React Projects/tictactoe/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../../node-addon-api/nothing.o
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/binding.o
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.10.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:958) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/sushrutkamat/Documents/React Projects/tictactoe/node_modules/@parcel/watcher/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/sushrutkamat/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/sushrutkamat/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.10.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/sushrutkamat/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/sushrutkamat/Documents/React Projects/tictactoe/node_modules/@parcel/watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Projects/tictactoe/node_modules/node-addon-api'
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/watcher/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/16.10.0_1/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/sushrutkamat/Documents/React Projects/tictactoe/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sushrutkamat/.npm/_logs/2021-10-08T04_16_03_379Z-debug.log
```

Current node version installed on system : v16.10.0.
Current npm verison installed on system: 7.24.0.
Following were installed using homebrew

Comment: I don't know how but I removed the project and tried npm install again today and it seems to be working all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the above issue by deleting the project and setting it up again. I don't know why it did not work in the first place but now it's working all of a sudden.